# Test connection to a third party website's account while testing using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use the following piece of code to connect to a website where I want to run some automated testing:

```
# create an instance of the driver 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('**root**\\chromedriver.exe')
# connect to "leboncoin"
connect_lbc(driver)

def connect_lbc(driver):
    driver.get('https://www.leboncoin.fr/')
    assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
    # press connection box
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"header\"]/section/section/aside/button"))
    connection_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"header\"]/section/section/aside/button")
    connection_box.click()
    # fill in info and connect
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_name('st_username'))
    name_box = driver.find_element_by_name('st_username')
    name_box.send_keys('**my_email_adress**')
    pwd_box = driver.find_element_by_name("st_passwd")
    pwd_box.send_keys('**my_pwd**')
    connect_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"popin-content\"]/section/main/section[1]/form/div[3]/div/input")
    connect_box.click()
```

The problem is that in order to complete my testing correctly, I need to remain connected to my account during the whole process. But sometimes, for a reason I can not identify a disconnection from my account occurs during the automated test. Therefore, I would need to identify when that happens and reconnect.

I would need some function like `isConnected()` that would return me a boolean but the problem is that I don't know how to write it using Selenium and Python.

Does anybody know how to deal with this type of issue?

Comment: It seems a server configuration issue, like terminate the connection after some idle amount of time. Is same behaviour observed when you perform activities manually in the browser also?  This is just one possibility (disconnect due to idle timeout). There might be other reasons as well.

Comment: It nevers happens when I manually use the browser, so you are probably right about the diagnosis, thanks! do you know a way to identify when that happens and reconnect?

Comment: If I had a way to test if I am connected, i would test it at key moments in my testing programs and reconnect if needed

Comment: then keep calling login method (keep the login related actives under one method) after making a check if isConnected() method return false. In isConnected method, try to find a web element which is present throughout the application (like email id or username). If you are able find it return True otherwise False.

Comment: Find out what is the idle timeout so that you keep calling login method in that interval of time (idle timeout) so that the user is logged in. **OR** you keep sending the requests so that existing session won't be killed by the server due to idle timeout.

Comment: Thanks a lot Naveen, I have just applied your first suggestion and it seems to work fine!

Comment: I leave the question open in case somebody knows how to identify when exactly this disconnection may appear and have a solution that would better deal with this